# How can you paint tile?

Tags: paint, ceramic-tile

Our bathroom is out of the 70's and the wife doesn't care for the colors. Remodeling is out of the question for now. Is there something I can use to paint over that ceramic tile so we can at least get a color she likes better?

I should clarify, the tile is on the wall no shower.

Comment: Painted tile will likely be worse than whatever is there now, cover it with floor mats as best you can until you can retile.

Comment: ^ agree if we're talking the floor, but I assume these are shower or wall tiles.

Comment: Painted tile will be ugly on both floors and walls, its still painted tile.

Comment: Agreed. But you can't put floor mats on the wall very easily. ;)

Comment: If it is the shower walls, a decorative shower curtain will hide it most of the time (except when showering).  The main point is, hide it until you can fix it.

Comment: It was just a thought... nothing too serious at this point.

Comment: Your next question will likely be "how can I strip paint from tiles".  Be strong!  Take her to the local home improvement store and show her the price of tile, then tell her to use her natural girl instincts to decorate and cover it up.

Comment: If you go paint route, you'll be out the cost of paint and time putting it on. I say give it a shot (and would suggest the epoxy-based paint route). If it's ugly now, you really have nothing to lose.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They make paint specifically for tile. It's typically an epoxy based paint.

Comment: A link to an example paint might help.

Comment: I've never used a particular brand to recommend one over another, but there's plenty of examples on google: http://www.google.com/search?q=tile%20paint

Answer (score 2):

You can prime the tiles with a sealer/primer designed to stick to tiles, and then paint with the paint of your choice. Here's an example of a [primer that claims to adhere to tile](http://www.homedepot.com/h_d1/N-5yc1v/R-100398391/h_d2/ProductDisplay?langId=-1&storeId=10051&catalogId=10053).

Good luck! Now you just have to find a paint color you can agree on. :)

Comment: You mean I have a choice? I believe the correct words are "yes dear".